# Tailwind CSS not compiling CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

So I am working with Tailwind CSS is not compiling my HTML CSS mentions.

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./public/logs.html"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you post other files as well such as your `package.json`, and the `.html` file where you are either importing the compiled CSS or where you are importing the CSS file with the `@tailwind` decorators?

### Options

1. You can either run `npx tailwindcss -i ./path_to_input.css -o ./path_to_output.css --watch` while you are developing and make sure to import the outputted CSS file in your `.html` file.
2. If you are developing with some sort of build system, then you can just add the below line to your `.html` file.

```html
<link href="path_to_output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

*In the case you are doing **option 2**, make sure your `output.css` file looks something like this:*

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: ```<div class="bg-gray-600">
    <fieldset id="userinfo">
        <img src="" id="userinfo" alt="" class="">
        <p class="username" id="username">Hi!</p>
    </fieldset>
</div>```
And,
```/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./public/logs.html"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}```

Comment: Right, but where are you importing your tailwind CSS file? I’d suggest you look over the installation instructions and see if you have created and imported your CSS file. 

Link to Tailwinds installation docs: [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

Comment: Hey, did you had ever an issue with the tailwind components and
tailwind utilities not getting compiled into CSS? On project I have this issue while on another no

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem all i did was restart vscode and reinstalled
npx tailwindcss -i ./path_to_input.css -o ./path_to_output.css --watch

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).